# Metamask signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, meta

Ребят всем привет, большая просьба к тем у кого есть опыт работы с Metamask. У меня задача привязать к профилю аккаунт Metamask. Перелопатил документацию и вроде я делаю все правильно. Отправляю на бекенд форму с 2 полями, id wallet и signature. В ответ мне приходит 400-ошибка с сервера: message: "Signature is not correct.". Что я делаю не так? буду очень признателен за помощь. Это мой косяк или возможна проблема с бекендом?

```html
const postConnect = async (userAddress, signature) => {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('accountAddress', userAddress);
  form.append('signature', signature);
  const data = await authClient().post(`profile/connectMetamask`, form);
  return data;
};

import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { postConnect } from '../../../service/user/metamask';

let provider = null;
let signer = null;
const message = 'Авторизация через Metamask';

export const metamaskForm = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    signer = await provider.getSigner();

    const userAddress = await signer.getAddress();
    const signature = await getSign();

    verifyMessage(message, userAddress, signature);

    await postConnect(userAddress, signature);

    window.ethereum.on('accountChanged', metamaskForm);
    window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', chainHandler);
  } else {
    alert('Установите приложение metamask для вашего браузера');
  }
};

const getSign = async () => {
  try {
    const signature = await signer.signMessage(message);
    return signature;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
};

const verifyMessage = async (message, userAddress, signature) => {
  try {
    const signerAddr = ethers.verifyMessage(message, signature);
    if (signerAddr !== userAddress) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
};

const chainHandler = () => {
  window.location.reload();
};
```